# Finding a superbase in a lattice of Voronoi first kind

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, lattices, geometry-of-numbers

An $n$-dimensional lattice in $\mathbb R^n$ is said to be of Voronoi’s first kind if it there exists $n+1$ vectors $b_1,\cdots b_{n+1}$ (called the superbase) such that

1. $\{b_1,\ldots,b_n \}$ is a basis,
2. $b_1+\cdots +b_{n+1}=0$,
3. $q_{ij}=b_i^Tb_j\le 0$ for all $i\ne j$. The $q_{ij}$ are called selling parameters.

Condition (2) is called the superbase condition and condition (3) the obtuse condition.

Given a lattice which is known to be Voronoi's first kind, are any methods known to find a superbase for it?

Answer (score 3):

In the paper [Finding a closest point in a lattice of Voronoi's first kind](http://staff.itee.uq.edu.au/vaughan/Publications/first-kind.pdf), the authors state in section 7 that:

> Given a lattice, is it possible to efficiently decide whether it is of Voronoi’s first kind?
> **Is it possible to efficiently find an obtuse superbasis if it exists**? It is suspected that
> the answer to this second question is no because an efficient solution would yield a
> solution to a known problem, that of determining whether a lattice is rectangular (has
> a basis consisting of pairwise orthogonal vectors) given an arbitrary basis [30].

The reference is to Lenstra and Silverberg's paper [Revisiting the Gentry-Szydlo Algorithm](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/430.pdf).